# Gradle: add config file to classpath

Tags: gradle

In a simple gradle project I have under the projects root a config folder with a config.json in it. I want to put this file on the path to read it.

```
    def myconfigfile = new File("config", "config.json")
    def configset = files(myconfigfile)

    task runExample ( dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec ) {
      main = 'com.example.LoadConfigExample'
      classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
      classpath.add(configset)
      args 'ARG1'
    }
```

In the Java file I'm using the following to load the file:

```
URL u = LoadConfigExample.class.getResource("config.json");
```

Would it be better just to use relative paths and load via the file system? I don't want to put the file under src/main/resources.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well the best option seems to refer to the `config.json` via `project.file` method, for docs see [here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#file(java.lang.Object)).

It will be:

```
project.file("confif${File.separator}config.json")
```